# Updating a table with different values for different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a situation like this:

```
update lskinproperty
set frn_lskin_stateid = 2
where frn_lskinid IN (61209, 61208)

update lskinproperty
set frn_lskin_stateid = 3
where frn_lskinid IN (72670, 56916)

update lskinproperty
set frn_lskin_stateid = 4
where frn_lskinid IN (55451)
```

If I run this three queries, it will do what exactly what I want however I feel there it should be a better way to do this. Does SQL Server has anything like case or switch or something similar where you can say for case equal to x do this and for case equal to y do something else and so on?

Comment: It sure does! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter for all the values of frn_lskinid at once and then use `case` to identify which value to assign for which frn_lskinid .

```
update lskinproperty
set frn_lskin_stateid = case 
        when frn_lskinid in (61209, 61208)
            then 2
        when frn_lskinid in (72670, 56916)
            then 3
        else 4
        end
where frn_lskinid in (72670, 56916, 61209, 61208, 55451)
```

The `else` here covers for the case when frn_lskinid is 55451 which is same as writing explicitly using another `when`:

```
update lskinproperty
set frn_lskin_stateid = case 
        when frn_lskinid in (61209, 61208)
            then 2
        when frn_lskinid in (72670, 56916)
            then 3
        when frn_lskinid = 55451
            then 4
        end
where frn_lskinid in (72670, 56916, 61209, 61208, 55451)
```

Comment: is else clause optional ?

Comment: @DoArNa not here. It covers the case when frn_lskinid is 55451

Comment: @DoArNa - Updated the answer with equivalent `when` based solution.

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't a real shortcut to doing this type of update. Using `case` forces you to supply the `id`s twice: once in the `case` clause and then again in the `where` clause. However, in case you have the values to change to in a tabular way, then you could do something like the following:

```
update tbl set frn_lskin_stateid=st
from (       select 61209 i,2 st
   union all select 61208,2
   union all select 72670,3
   union all select 56916,3
   union all select 55451,4 ) tvalues
inner join lskinproperty tbl on frn_lskinid=i;
```

In a real application `tvalues` would most likely be a table with your target values, but, of course, you can also supply the values in a sub-query with several `union all` lines like shown above.

For a demo see here: http://rextester.com/NDQGL19748

Comment: When you say "Using case forces you to supply the ids twice", are you saying that it is time consuming or also hurts the performance of database?

Comment: @DoArNa: No, I believe that working with `case`, as shown in GurV's solution is a very effective way. But compiling the command by hand is a little cumbersome and it gives way to making mistakes. On the other hand, in my approach you will have to re-type the target value for each id, which is also a bit repetitive ...